# String parsing in Haskell

Tags: string, parsing, haskell

I am very new to Haskell and am currently trying to solve a problem that requires some string parsing. My input String contains a comma-delimited list of words in quotes. I want to parse this single string into a list of the words as Strings. Where should I start learning about parsing such a String? Is there a partuclar module and/or functions that will be helpful?

p.s. Please don't post a full solution. I am just asking for a pointer to a starting place so I can learn how to do it.

Comment: [split](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split) would probably be useful. Or you can use real parsers like [parsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec).

Comment: It sounds like the words are delimited by commas *and* quotes?

Comment: @BenMillwood The words are surrounded by quotes and delimited by commas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `String`s are simply lists of `Char`s in Haskell, [Data.List](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html) would be a good place to start looking (in the interest of learning Haskell).

For more complex cases (where commas may be nested inside quotes and should be ignored, for example), [parsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec) (as Daniel mentioned) would be a better solution.

Also, if you're looking to parse CSVs you may try [Text.CSV](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/csv/0.1.2/doc/html/Text-CSV.html), though I've not tried it, so I can't say how helpful it'll be.

Answer (score 8):

I finally decided to roll my own parsing functions since this is such a simple situation. I have learned a lot about Haskell since I first posted this question and want to document my solution here:

```
split :: Char -> String -> [String]
split _ "" = []
split c s = firstWord : (split c rest)
    where firstWord = takeWhile (/=c) s
          rest = drop (length firstWord + 1) s

removeChar :: Char -> String -> String
removeChar _ [] = []
removeChar ch (c:cs)
    | c == ch   = removeChar ch cs
    | otherwise = c:(removeChar ch cs)

main = do
    handle <- openFile "input/names.txt" ReadMode
    contents <- hGetContents handle
    let names = sort (map (removeChar '"') (split ',' contents))
    print names
    hClose handle
```

Answer (score 7):

The most powerful solution is a parser combinator.  Haskell has several of these, but the foremost that come to my mind are:

- [parsec](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Parsec): a very good general-purpose parsing library
- [attoparsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.10.2.0): a faster version of parsec, which sacrifices the quality of error messages and some other features for extra speed
- [uu-parsinglib](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/uu-parsinglib): a very powerful parsing library

The big advantage of parser combinators is that it is very easy to define parsers using `do` notation (or `Applicative` style, if you prefer).

If you just want some quick and simple string manipulation capabilities, then consult the `text` library (for high-performance byte-encoded strings), or `Data.List` (for ordinary list-encoded strings), which provide the necessary functions to manipulate strings.

Comment: When I was a noob I could not make heads nor tails of uu-parsinglib. I haven't tried it since then, but I wouldn't exactly call it friendly.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a particularly cheeky way to proceed:

```
parseCommaSepQuotedWords :: String -> [String]
parseCommaSepQuotedWords s = read ("[" ++ s ++ "]")
```

This might work but it's very fragile and rather silly. Essentially you are using the fact that the Haskell way of writing lists of strings *almost* coincides with your way, and hence the built-in `Read` instance is *almost* the thing you want. You could use `reads` for better error-reporting but in reality you probably want to do something else entirely.

In general, `parsec` is *really* worth taking a look at - it's a joy to use, and one of the things that originally really got me excited about Haskell. But if you want a homegrown solution, I often write simple things using `case` statements on the result of `span` and `break`. Suppose you are looking for the next semicolon in the input. Then `break (== ';') inp` will return `(before, after)`, where:

- `before` is the content of `inp` up to (and not including) the first semicolon (or all of it if there is none)
- `after` is the rest of the string:

  - if `after` is not empty, the first element is a semicolon
  - regardless of what else happens, `before ++ after == inp`

So to parse a list of statements separated by semicolons, I might do this:

```
parseStmts :: String -> Maybe [Stmt]
parseStmts inp = case break (== ';') inp of
  (before, _ : after) -> -- ...
    -- ^ before is the first statement
    --     ^ ignore the semicolon
    --           ^ after is the rest of the string
  (_, []) -> -- inp doesn't contain any semicolons
```

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of having a complete answer for those who happen upon this question, [Data.Text](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/0.11.2.2/doc/html/Data-Text.html) has some good functions as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use parsec for anything that that is 'real work'.

For a introduction read https://therning.org/magnus/archives/tag/parsec

Comment: This link is now at http://therning.org/magnus/posts/2007-05-27-289-adventures-in-parsing.html; see https://wiki.haskell.org/Parsec Sec. 5.2 for other links in the series and additional resources

Comment: http://therning.org/ is now a dead link